# how do I use javascript to send data from a textbox to a specific cell in excel and hit enter

Tags: javascript, excel

Okay, All I need to know is, how do I use javascript to send data from a textbox to a specific cell in excel and hit enter (and not use the POST method). I know in VBA it would be 'sendkeys', (lame I know but its what I need.) You heard it. I want to type, 'rumandcoke' in a text box, hit submit and make the javascript put that 'rumandcoke' into, lets say, A1 in an excel file. Dont worry about the file and how to access it, I just need the syntax on how to send that info! That's it! 
 Yes I can. The line doesn't need to know where to search for the file. All that info is already on the script. It opens just fine. It can retrieve info like a charm. The whole code is not important, just the line that says, "update this Excel cell with the info from this textbox, and hit enter" just a generic syntax. is the code nec for that, cuz its at work so I don't have it with me. Just a generic line, is it even possible for javascript to update an Excel cell and press 'enter' afterwards? Maybe its something I have to put together since the javascript bible doesn't even have anything on it.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Where is the JavaScript - in a browser or a standalone script file?  Where is the Excel file - local or on a server?  You can't ask a question like this and say "don't worry about the details" - **it's all details**

Answer (score 0):

am assuming you are creating VBArray.  In for loop please add for(var cells in ...)
or try  for(var i = 0; i < jsRangeArray.length; i++) also getElementById('searchMember')  mention id='searchMember' in

Comment: At this moment, all I want to learn is how to send data to a specific cell in excel. That's it.